# Loading an HTML5 video player from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, video, dynamic

I have an array of videos and I would like to load them into the set video player that is currently on the page.  Here's what I have:

```
var current = 0;

var videos = ["01", "02", "03", "04"];

function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex ;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;

}

function shuffleAll(){
    shuffle(videos);
}

function loadVideo(){
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    var mp4 = document.getElementById('mp4');
    d = new Date();

    mp4.src = "videos/" + videos[current] + '.mp4';
    alert(mp4.src);
    video.load();
    video.play();

}
```

And my HTML:

```
<body onLoad="shuffleAll()">

<a href="" onClick="javascript:loadVideo();">Load Video</a><br>
<video id="video" controls width="560">
     <source id="mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
</body>
```

But I click my Load Video Button, and it doesn't do anything.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pause the video then load the video then play it. It's a tricky son o bitch really. You'll need to add the listener to a videobutton (changing source via randomizing or something)

```
videobutton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
   video.pause();
   mp4.setAttribute('src', 'videos/' + videos[current] + '.mp4');
   video.load();
   video.play();
},false);
```

This will work.

```
var current = 0;

var videos = ["01", "02", "03", "04"];

function shuffle(array) {
 var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex ;
 // While there remain elements to shuffle...
 while (0 !== currentIndex) {
 // Pick a remaining element...
 randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
 currentIndex -= 1;
 // And swap it with the current element.
 temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
 array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
 array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
}

 return array;

}

function shuffleAll(){
   shuffle(videos);
} 

function loadVideo(){
   var video = document.getElementById('video');
   var mp4 = document.getElementById('mp4');
   d = new Date();
   video.pause();
   mp4.setAttribute('src', 'videos/' + videos[current] + '.mp4');
   video.load();
   video.play();
 }
```

Comment: No it's a cached object. so say your button is `<div id="next">NEXT</div>` so our videobutton would be `var videobutton = document.getElementById('next');

I'll fix it to work with yours

Comment: I'm going to need jQuery for this, huh.

Comment: No never -_- if jQuery can do it, JavaScript can do it.