# How to open a new video every time the page is reloaded in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a beginner in Web development, but now have started to write cool websites. I applied a video background to my webpage, did all the stylings, and looks cool, but how can I change it every time I reload the HTML page?

```
<video id="vidtest" autoplay muted loop>
      <source src= "videos/vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading an HTML5 video player from Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26001737/loading-an-html5-video-player-from-array)

Answer (score 3):

Create an array with your video paths in it, randomly select an array item, then set it as the `src` attribute of your video source:

```js
var source = document.getElementById('video-source');

var videos = [
  "vid1.mp4",
  "vid2.mp4",
  "vid3.mp4"
];

var randomVideo = videos[Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length)];

source.setAttribute('src', randomVideo);
```

```html
<video id="vidtest" autoplay muted loop>
  <source id="video-source" src= "videos/vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```